# RedShift to_char format not giving desired results

Tags: amazon-redshift, to-char

I need to convert my timestamps to the following format **YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.0**. Please note the 'T' in the middle. For example 2014-09-04T13:05:10.0.

I tried the following:

```
select to_char(timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.0') from table;
```

However, RedShift is interpreting the 'TH' as an ordinal number suffix (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_formating.html). Therefore, I'm getting results like 2014-03-23RDH24:26:36.0.

Therefore, I added a space after the 'T' and tried trimming the space out.

```
select trim(' ' FROM to_char(timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DDT HH24:MI:SS.0')) from table;
```

However, the trim did not actually remove the space. My results were like 2014-03-23T 07:26:36.0.

I also tried escaping by using the backslash, but that didn't work either.

How do I achieve the desired format without spaces?

Answer (score 3):

```
upper(to_char(GetDate(),'YYYY-MM-DDtHH24:MI:SS.0'))
```

works too.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working

```
select concat(to_char(timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DDT'), to_char(timestamp,'HH24:MI:SS.0')) from table;
```